# Differences between WorkSheet.Autofilter vs ListObject.AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

There is no explanation on MSDN about the difference between the .Autofilter property of a sheet and a table. I would appreciate your clarifications. All the best.

It's taken me a lot of trial and error to come to the conclusion that both the sheet and a table have .Autofilter objects associated with it.

After doing some tests I add to the question the following:

A sheet can only have one contiguous filtered cell range, but in addition, each table in the sheet has its own autofilter.

Therefore, the`Activesheet.ShowAllData` statement clears the sheet filter if the active cell is outside any table, but only clears the table filter if the active cell is inside a table.

Comment: pretty sure they are exactly the same? if you look in the object browser they both reference an `AutoFilter` class in the main excel object

Comment: If the only data on a sheet are in a table, the `AutoFilter` property for both the sheet and the ListObject may or may not be the same (I've had the sheet's `AutoFilter` nothing and had it matching a table's `AutoFilter` and haven't figured out when it is and when it isn't). If there is a filter outside a table, it will be in the sheet's `AutoFilter` property. You can have a filter on a table and outside a table on the same sheet, and their `AutoFilter` properties will differ.